# Instruments reporting memory leak whenever AVSpeechSynthesizer is used to read text

Tags: memory-leaks, ios7, avfoundation, avspeechsynthesizer

Everytime I use AVSpeechSynthesizer to speak text Instruments reports a memory leak in the AXSpeechImplementation library. Here's the code I'm using to make the call:

```
AVSpeechUtterance *speak = [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:text];
speak.voice = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:@"en-US"];
speak.rate = AVSpeechUtteranceMaximumSpeechRate * .2;
[m_speechSynth speakUtterance:speak];
```

Here's the link to the Instruments screenshot
http://imageshack.com/a/img690/7993/b9w5.png

Comment: "Is anyone else leaking memory" is not a specific, answerable question here. (Possible answers are "Yes, someone else is", "No, no one else is", or "Somewhere, someone probably is", none of which are useful to you or any future readers of this site.) Please read the [SO question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/172661), and then edit your question to make it more clear and specific about the problem you're asking us to help you solve.

Comment: You've still not asked a specific question, I'm afraid. :) It's better, but there still has to be a question. Visit the link I posted.

Comment: Ditto on getting this error. Anyone file a bug report?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For what it is worth - yes, I see exactly the same 16byte leak on every utterance from the speech synthesizer. So either it is a leak in Apple's code or we are both making the same error somewhere!

Ali

Comment: I second that. I'm also seeing the same 16 byte memory leak as well.

Comment: are you releasing the AVSpeechUtterance?  When are you allowed to do that... on the stop?

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by declaring the AVSpeechSynthesizer as a global variable

```java
static let synth = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
```