# IOS OBJECTIVE C AVSpeechSynthesizer slowing down image processing

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv

hi in my app I am detecting red color of flowers and using AV synthesizer to speak if the color is red.  The code works fine, but whenever the speech is being spoken, it slows down the image processing - it sometimes freezes the screen.  Is there an efficient way of doing this?  My code is below:

```
#import “ViewController.h"
{
BOOL redcolor;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
redcolor = FALSE;
}


- (void)processImage:(cv::Mat&)image


    {
cv::Mat myflower = image;
if (redcolor = TRUE) {
NSString *strtext1 = @“Color is Red";

    AVSpeechSynthesizer *synthesizer = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc]init];

    AVSpeechUtterance *speechutt = [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:strtext1];
    [speechutt setRate:0.5f];
     speechutt.voice = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:@"en-us"];
    [synthesizer speakUtterance:speechutt];
}
}
```

Comment: AVSpeechSynthesizer obviously uses some processor capacity but not much and the speech is automatically spoken on another thread. Is this on a real device or simulator?

Comment: it is on real device in my iPhone 6.  Actually I had two problems 1) the image will freeze when speech synthesizer was speaking and 2)

Comment: the first problem i think is solved now because the the synthesizer was inside my detention segment, i defined a boolean within that and called it outside which then calls the synthesizer.  2)  the code works as intended when my phone is connected to my MAC with XCODE using USB chord and also the first time I disconnected the chord and for 2nd time i disconnected the chord and run it on he phone by pressing the app button.  But after that the screen will freeze and only way I can get this running again is if I power off my phone . I then thought it has to do with terminating the synthesizer.

Comment: I added the following code, i have not tried that yet.  Does the synthesizer has to be terminated or else it can do strange things?  (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
 [self.synthesizer pauseSpeakingAtBoundary:AVSpeechBoundaryImmediate];

Comment: sorry let me clarify on problem 2.  code works when it is phone is connected to XCODE and first time it is disconnected.  For 2nd time onwards on phone itself it will freeze (not connected to XCODE).

Comment: You should not need to terminate the synthesiser manually (the code you posted in the comment does not do that anyway, it just pauses any ongoing speech). There is a small memory leak in synthesiser (see [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19991494/2466193)) but that should not cause this problem.

Comment: When the app stops everything will reset, so any problems with synthesiser not deallocating will automatically stop. However be sure that your app has stopped - closing the app by pressing the home button will only (initially) put it into the background. When debugging, to stop the App: press Stop on XCode if connected or if not connected kill the app (doubles press Home then swipe the app upwards) to ensure that it dies. When you do that does the problem go away? If not please update your code so we can see the latest.

Comment: Ali, thanks your suggestion works great.